# How to log a output status of each dll's files registered using regsvr32 command in power shell script

Tags: powershell, dll, regsvr32

I want to register few dll's using `regsvr32` command in powershell.

I have created a foreach command to do it. In this case, some dll's might fail to register and I want to log each dll status in a log file.

This is what I have created so far

```
$dllfiles = @("1.dll","2.dll","3.dll","4.dll")

$dllfiles | ForEach {regsvr32 /s $_}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the command in `cmd` for it to set `$?` and `$LASTEXITCODE` correctly:

```
$dllfiles | % {
  & cmd /c regsvr32 /s $_
  if ($?) {
    "$_ registered correctly."
  } else {
    "Registration of $_ failed. ($LASTEXITCODE)"
  }
}
```

[<strike>http://huddledmasses.org/register-dll-calling-regsvr32-without-messageboxes-in-powershell/</strike>] (page was apparently [removed by the author](http://huddledmasses.org/blog/missing-content/index.html))

Comment: Link to the article in the WebArchive: [Register DLL – Calling RegSvr32 without MessageBoxes in PowerShell](https://web.archive.org/web/20120428195356/http://huddledmasses.org/register-dll-calling-regsvr32-without-messageboxes-in-powershell)